# How send xml without any transformation in SOAPHandler

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, handlers

IBM WebSphere Jax-WS RI framework.
I have a chunckHandler.
I need send a one line xml response to client.
i make oneline xml. Debuging shows whats all ok - xml is onelined.
But before send the framework make a "pretty-print" output.
It needed for signing and any xml transformations doesn`t need.
General question: how send xml data without any transformation in SOAPHandler.

```
public class SignHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{


        private String makeOneLineXml(String xml) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(xml));
            String line=null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line.trim());
            }
            return sb.toString();

        }

 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {


    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    //for response message only, true for outbound messages, false for inbound
    if(isRequest){

    try{
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();                   
        Document orig = soapEnv.getOwnerDocument();
        orig = 
// I need  send to client one-line-xml
        XmlUtils.deserialize(makeOneLineXml(XmlUtils.serializeNode(signedSoap, false, false)));
        soapMsg.saveChanges();



           //tracking
           soapMsg.writeTo(System.out); // In CONSOLE ALL ok. Xml is one line

        }catch(SOAPException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        }

      //continue other handler chain
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All tests i make in SoapUI. But by default in soapUI response is pretty-print formated.
All problems in this.

to replace optional soap xml in SoapMessage you could use this:

```
 private SOAPMessage makeSOAPMessage(String msg)
        {
        try {

            SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();

            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(msg);                        

            message.getSOAPPart().setContent(new StreamSource(sReader));
            message.saveChanges();
             return message;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        }   
.....................

 context.setMessage(makeSOAPMessage(yours_xml_string));
```

After this you receive in client exactly this xml_string.
Its usefull for xmldsig, jax-wss security issues.